# WordPress show posts within while() loop based on condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 8 posts for example.

Here **3 posts** out of 8 posts is sticky and 2 posts has **paid_placement** meta key out of those **3 posts**

**Now, within while loop I want to show:**

1) those posts on top which has **is_sticky() === true** and **don't** have any **paid_placement** meta key.
2) After that those posts which has **is_sticky() === true** and have **paid_placement** meta key.
2) After that custom post type posts ( **pro_event** as post type).
3) after that all other posts

Now, I am very much confused how to make it happend in WordPress while() loop. Can you guys help me?

**My code:**

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    if ( is_sticky() && false === ( 'paid' == strtolower( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'paid_placement')[0] ) ) ) {
        the_title();
        echo '<hr/>';
        continue;
    }
    the_title();
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

**Updated:**

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    if ( is_sticky() && false === ( 'paid' == strtolower( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'paid_placement')[0] ) ) ) {
        //the_title();
        var_dump('paid' == strtolower( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'paid_placement')[0] ) );
        echo '<hr/>';
        continue;
    }
    //the_title();
    var_dump('paid' == strtolower( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'paid_placement')[0] ) );
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

**output:**

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Comment: Could you please provide here var_dump(( 'paid' == strtolower( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'paid_placement')[0] ) ) )); here?

Comment: hi @creativeartbd your updated code has var_dump in 2 places, so you can't tell if it's dumping from inside or out of your conditional.

Comment: inside the loop.